# redirect using htaccess, if a url contains special character

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I want to do permanent redirect using htaccess. For eg :- **Redirect permanent /presskit http://example.com/**  works fine. But the problem is if it contains special characters, redirect does not works. **Redirect permanent /content/how-aaa-loneliness%3A-being  http://example.com/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Redirect permanent "/content/how-aaa-loneliness:-being" http://xxx.com/
```

Apache already removed the %-encoding for you, so just add the normal character, optionally adding quotes.

> The old URL-path is a case-sensitive (%-decoded) path beginning with a
>   slash.

Comment: also i want a redirect for `shattered%3A-teenager%2526%2523039%3Bs-healing`. I tried `shattered:-teenager%2526%2523039%3Bs-healing` . but din't worked. How to proceed for this. For eg: I also wanted a redirect for `Media%20kit%201`.

Comment: `shattered%3A-teenager%2526%2523039%3Bs-healing` doesn't make sense. It is %encoded twice. If that is really what you want just decode it once and you get `shattered:-teenager%26%23039;s-healing`. %20 means `space`, so `Media%20kit%201` will become `Media kit 1`. Note that spaces are only allowed if the path is between quotes (`"..."`).